# Fragment inflate to fill container programatically without any XML file?

Tags: android, android-fragments

On my Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(???, container, false);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("Touch", event.getX() + " "+ event.getY());
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I would like my fragment to stretch to fill whatever container it is attached to, so then I can get touch event anywhere inside that container. How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Fragments are always accompanied with activities where is the activity code!

Comment: Actually I have no control over the activity. I am using Unity, and I got the activity via `UnityPlayer.currentActivity`. That activity sets a view that is always full screen..

Comment: Your fragment by default it is always match parent then!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the parent `match_parent` programatically then you will have to use:

```
view.getLayoutParams().height= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
view.getLayoutParams().width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Although this could be easily done in xml.